# Multiline regex replacement in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to remove everything between two captions in postgres:

```
regexp_replace(text, 'caption1:[\S\s\n\r]+?:', '', 'ig') AS text
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence
SQL state: 2201B
```

It looks like it doesn't allow me to match with `\S (any non-whitespace character)`

Example text:

```
Lorem ipsum

Caption1:
I want this text to be removed.
And this line too.


Caption2:
Consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

It should become:

```
Lorem ipsum

Consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html):

> Within bracket expressions, \d, \s, and \w lose their outer brackets,
>   and \D, \S, and \W are illegal. (So, for example, [a-c\d] is
>   equivalent to [a-c[:digit:]]. Also, [a-c\D], which is equivalent to
>   [a-c^[:digit:]], is illegal.)

So your regex should be:

```
caption1:[^[:space:][:space:]\n\r]+?:
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't remove anything. But thanks for the inspiration to use the not ^ operator, that does the trick for me too!

Answer (score 1):

This eventually worked for me:

```
regexp_replace(text, 'caption1:[^:]+?:', '', 'ig') AS text
```

Comment: See my answer for a more optimized solution and explanation why your original solution did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need *two* backslashes if you want to use an escaped character class, e.g. use `\\s` instead of `\s`.  But in any case, I don't think your logic really requires this.  Instead, you might be able to use the following query:

```
SELECT 'Caption1: ' || right(text, char_length(text) - position('Caption2' in text) + 1)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: You only need two backlashes if you changed the default configuration to **not** use [standard conforming strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS). Otherwise the backslash is **not** a special character that needs escaping in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The `[\S\s\n\r]` cannot work in PostgreSQL because this engine does not support shorthand Perl-like character classes (like `\S`, `\d`, `\W`, etc.) inside bracket expressions (i.e. inside `[...]`). They are parsed as `\` and the letter after them.

You need to use

```
regexp_replace(text, 'caption1:[^:]+:', '', 'ig') AS text
```

Note that `+` is a regular greedy quantifier that matches one or more occurrences of the pattern it modifies. The quantified pattern is `[^:]`. It is a character class (or also called a bracket expression) that is *negated* using the `^` char that goes right after `^`. So, `[^:]` matches *any char other than* a `:` **including** line break chars.

You do not need `?` after `+` as the lazy pattern here, in this case, will work slower than the greedy version.

So, use `caption1:[^:]+:`:

- `caption1:` - a literal substring
- `[^:]+` - 1 or more chars other than `:`
- `:` - a literal `:`